# How to make an open file unmodifiable

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a file that is open by a program for writing (it's a log4j log). I want to test a theory about what happens if the file system becomes read-only while the file is still open. I haven't been able to re-mount the file system (because it is 'busy'), is there a way I can force that file to no longer be writable--even to the processes that already have it open?

I believe the filesystem is ext3.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious? sudo chattr +i filename?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Yes. The open process was still able to write to the file.